# strong operator topology and $L_2$ norm

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In many places, I saw that SOT coincides with the norm $\tau(X^*X)^{1/2}$, $X\in M$, where $M$ is a semifinite von Neumann algebra and $\tau$ is a semifinite faithful normal trace on $M$. I want a reference about this argument but I just can not find it.

Comment: I recently needed this result and spent quite some time looking for a reference, so I'll leave it here to spare others the work: It is Proposition 5.3. of Chapter III in Takesaki's book on operator algebras. In fact, one does not need that $\tau$ is a trace, it is true for arbitrary normal faithful states. The proof is similar to the one in the answer to this question, just that one uses the commutant in the GNS representation (this is needed if the state is not a trace).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have seen a reference for this. I guess it's "folklore"? I will answer for $M$ finite, but the argument is basically the same for semifinite (you need to believe that you can do GNS there too).

They induce the same topology on bounded sets. Say $M\subset B(H)$. What happens is that if you do GNS for $\tau$, you get a normal faithful representation $\pi_\tau:M\to B(K)$. It follows that $\pi_\tau$ is sot-sot continuous (see, for instance, 
Corollary 7.1.16 in Kadison Ringrose).

So, suppose that $x_j\to0$ sot in $M$. Then $\pi_\tau(x_j)\to0$ sot in $B(K)$. Thus,
$$
0=\lim \langle \pi_\tau(x_j)\Omega,\pi_\tau(x_j)\Omega\rangle_K=\tau(x_j^*x_j).
$$
Conversely, if $\tau(x_j^*x_j)\to0$ then,  for any $y\in M$, 
$$
\|\pi_\tau(x_j)y\Omega\|^2=\langle \pi_\tau(x_j)y\Omega,\pi_\tau(x_j)y\Omega\rangle_K
=\tau(y^*x_j^*x_jy)=\tau(x_jyy^*x_j^*)\leq\|y\|^2\,\tau(x_jx_j^*)\to0. 
$$
Now, since we are assuming that $\{x_j\}$ is bounded, we can do the following: let $\xi\in K$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $y\in M$ such that $\|\xi-y\Omega\|<\varepsilon. $ Thus
$$
\|\pi_\tau(x_j)\xi\|\leq\|x_j\|\,\|\xi-y\Omega\|+\|\pi_\tau(x_j)y\Omega\|\leq k\varepsilon +\|\pi_\tau(x_j)y\Omega\|.
$$
Then 
$$
0\leq \limsup \|\pi_\tau(x_j)\xi\|\leq  k\varepsilon +\limsup \|\pi_\tau(x_j)y\Omega\|=k\varepsilon. 
$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we get $\lim \|\pi_\tau(x_j)\xi\|=0$, so $\pi_\tau(x_j)\to0$ (sot). We can apply 7.1.16 in KR to $\pi_\tau^{-1}$, and so $x_j\to0$ (sot).

Comment: THX! You really help me a lot in learning VNA. Although I have already fixed it out in some case, I still really appreciate. BTW, is it also true for any semifinite VNA?

Comment: In a non-finite semifinite von Neumann algebra,  $\tau (x^*x) $ is not finite for all $x $, so you certainly cannot test convergence for those $x $. But the argument above works for the "trace-class" operators within $M $.